# I get AttributeError on micro:bit examples

Tags: python, micropython, bbc-microbit

I have been trying the micro:bit radio examples but I can't get them to work as explained in, for example,

```
radio.send_string("Hello World")
```

will show the following error

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'send_string'
```

However if I use

```
radio.send("Hello World")
```

the program works just fine. It happens in a lot of the instructions that are part of the docs, for example when trying to use

```
input.light_level()
```

I get

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'light_level'
```

but the following, which I cannot find on the docs, works fine

```
display.read_light_level()
```

What am I missing?

Edit: I am using the online micro:bit python editor on Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two python editors available online which use two different Python libraries.

1. MakeCode: https://makecode.microbit.org/#editor
2. https://python.microbit.org/v/2

It looks like you are using the second editor which is using MicroPython and is documented at:
https://microbit-micropython.readthedocs.io/